# How to union two complex queries querying complex objects?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, linq

I am quite new to entity framework so I am confused now. I have these two queries:

```
var usersQuery =
            from role in this.dbContext.Set<Model.ApplicationRole>()
            join ru in dbContext.Set<Model.ApplicationRoleUser>() on role.Id equals ru.ApplicationRoleId into rus
            from ru in rus.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join user in dbContext.Set<Model.User>() on ru.UserId equals user.Id into users
            from user in users.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where
                (ru != null && ru.ApplicationId == application.Id)
             && (roleId == null || ru.ApplicationRoleId == roleId.Value)
            group role by user into grps

            select
                new RoleActor
                {
                    Actor =
                        new Actor
                        {
                            AccountName = grps.Key.AccountName,
                            DisplayName =
                                (grps.Key.DisplayName ?? string.Empty) != string.Empty
                                    ? grps.Key.DisplayName
                                    : grps.Key.CommonName,
                            DomainName = grps.Key.DomainName,
                            Email = grps.Key.Email ?? string.Empty,
                            CompanyCode = grps.Key.CompanyCode,
                            AdGuid = grps.Key.AdGuid,
                            CommonName = grps.Key.CommonName
                        },
                    Type = Model.ActorType.User,
                    RoleNames = grps.Select(role => role.Name).ToList()
                };

        var groupsQuery =
            from role in this.dbContext.Set<Model.ApplicationRole>()
            join rg in dbContext.Set<Model.ApplicationRoleGroup>() on role.Id equals rg.ApplicationRoleId into rgs
            from rg in rgs.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join @group in dbContext.Set<Model.Group>() on rg.GroupId equals @group.Id into groups
            from @group in groups.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where
                (rg != null && rg.ApplicationId == application.Id)
             && (roleId == null || rg.ApplicationRoleId == roleId.Value)
            group role by @group into grps
            select
                new RoleActor
                {
                    Actor =
                        new Actor
                        {
                            AccountName = grps.Key.AccountName,
                            DisplayName =
                                (grps.Key.DisplayName ?? string.Empty) != string.Empty
                                    ? grps.Key.DisplayName
                                    : grps.Key.CommonName,
                            DomainName = grps.Key.DomainName,
                            Email = string.Empty,
                            CompanyCode = string.Empty,
                            AdGuid = grps.Key.AdGuid,
                            CommonName = grps.Key.CommonName
                        },
                    Type = Model.ActorType.Group,
                    RoleNames = grps.Select(role => role.Name).ToList()
                };
```

I need to union these two queries. But when I try to use extension method Union, I get exception:

> The 'Distinct' operation cannot be applied to the collection
>   ResultType of the specified argument. Parameter name: argument

I wanted to concat queries and then do something like:

```
queryConcatResult.GroupBy(x => x.Key).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
```

However when I use method Concat, I get exception:

> The nested query is not supported. Operation1='UnionAll'
>   Operation2='MultiStreamNest'

I will be grateful for any hint.

Comment: I guess the `RoleNames` projection is causing the not supported nested union. But the queries are overcomplicated and IMO contain unnecessary group operations. If you have navigation properties, the queries should be quite simple. Looks like you are trying to get user and groups along with their roles as a concatenated result set? And then what?

Comment: @IvanStoev - you see it right, I need users and groups along with the roles, later in code there is pagination for the results, getting actual data for specific page and passing it to the ui component

Comment: Too bad. Quick and dirty approach is to perform the concat in memory, but that would be overkill when used for pagination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible (at least with EF) to perform union or concat of queries that contain nested collection (for instance the result of `group by` or `RoleNames` as in your case).

The solution is to remove the grouping from the base queries, create uniform projection, concat and then do the grouping.

Something like this:

(1)

```
var usersQuery =
    from user in dbContext.Set<Model.User>()
    join ru in dbContext.Set<Model.ApplicationRoleUser>() on user.Id equals ru.UserId
    join role in this.dbContext.Set<Model.ApplicationRole>() on ru.ApplicationRoleId equals role.Id
    where ru.ApplicationId == application.Id
        && (roleId == null || ru.ApplicationRoleId == roleId.Value)
    select new
    {
        Actor = new Actor
        {
            AccountName = user.AccountName,
            DisplayName = (user.DisplayName ?? "") != "" ? user.DisplayName : user.CommonName,
            DomainName = user.DomainName,
            Email = user.Email ?? "",
            CompanyCode = user.CompanyCode,
            AdGuid = user.AdGuid,
            CommonName = user.CommonName
        },
        Type = Model.ActorType.User,
        Role = role,
    };
```

(2)

```
var groupsQuery =
    from @group in dbContext.Set<Model.Group>()
    join rg in dbContext.Set<Model.ApplicationRoleGroup>() on @group.Id equals rg.GroupId
    join role in this.dbContext.Set<Model.ApplicationRole>() on rg.ApplicationRoleId equals role.Id
    where rg.ApplicationId == application.Id
        && (roleId == null || rg.ApplicationRoleId == roleId.Value)
    select new
    {
        Actor = new Actor
        {
            AccountName = @group.AccountName,
            DisplayName = (@group.DisplayName ?? "") != "" ? @group.DisplayName : @group.CommonName,
            DomainName = @group.DomainName,
            Email = "",
            CompanyCode = "",
            AdGuid = @group.AdGuid,
            CommonName = @group.CommonName
        },
        Type = Model.ActorType.Group,
        Role = role,
    };
```

(3)

```
var actorsQuery =
    from a in usersQuery.Concat(groupsQuery)
    group a by new { a.Actor, a.Type } into g
    select new RoleActor
    {
        Actor = g.Key.Actor,
        Type = g.Key.Type,
        RoleNames = g.Select(a => a.Role.Name).ToList()
    };
```

*Side note:* Although using `string.Empty` is a good programming practice, you'd better avoid it in EF queries because EF does not recognize it as constant and generates additional SQL query parameters.

Comment: well, it helped me a lot, thank you, although didn't solve the problem entirely... at the end we were three programmer and spent afternoon with this glitch and considered is to be little bit buggy, so I hanged approach a little